# Hide button if ListView.Text is empty

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listview, button

My program is a windows form application. I have multiple button inside my form and one ListView control. Each button displaying different information inside the `ListView1.Text` and not all user could view all information refer to their role. For example if user is a student, he can only see information from `Btn1.Text`, `Btn2.Text`, `Btn5.Text` and the rest button will display empty inside the `ListView1.Text`. So I want those button that does not displaying any information inside the ListView to become **invisible**. How would I do that? Thank you.

Comment: Are you asking how to hide the buttons? If so then you could btnbutton.visible = false

Comment: Do you mean like add a code `If ListView1.Text = " " Then Btn1.Visible = False End If` ??

Comment: It would be more like if user = student then btnbutton.visible = true

Comment: I think that even not close for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

In cases like this, I will create a class implemeting `INotifyPropertyChanged`, to contain the `state` of various controls, for example their visibility, and I will then use simple Windows Forms Data Binding to bind the `Visibility` property of the form's controls on the value in this "UIStatus" object.

Centralizing the UI state into an object is a good paradygm to follow, which is actually very close to MVVM. As your user interacts with the form, the UIStatus is updated, and the Windows Forms Binding mechanism will take care of setting the visibility, or even the enability of your controls.

Using this approach prevents having to loop through the Controls collection on the Form and execute all kind of logic within this loop which, to make sense, would have to be tied to a timer, or something to trigger it periodically.

I find that setting the properties of this UIStatus object as part of your user interaction is much better, as the Windows Forms Data Binding will happen "under the hood".

Cheers

Comment: I might need to study implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`. This kinda new to me. Never used it before.

Comment: @Emerald it forms part of the "backbone" of Data Binding in Windows Forms application, and when  you implement this interface in your own classes, it opens up such possibilities where "observers" can be notified of changes in an observed object, and then through Data Binding, you can change the property of a Control, such as its visibility or enablity. Very powerful stuff. I highly recommend the book "Data Binding With Windows Forms 2.0" by Bryan Noyes. Even if it's a bit old, those interfaces have changed very little since the days of .NET 2.0

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
{
     if (control is Button)
     {
          if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(((Button)control).Text))
          {
                ((Button)controls).Visible = false;
          }
     }
}
```

edit:Replace var with Control

Comment: How do I apply this in `VB.Net`?

Comment: i don't know VB but maybe someone can edit it to VB.but i think it doesn't diffrent .

Comment: http://converter.telerik.com/ I used this to convert your coding to VB.Net but the `var` is error. Never use that word in VB

Comment: `string.IsNullOrEmpty(((Button)controls).Text)` Does this refer to if ListView is empty?

Comment: I tried your coding but is doesn't go through to the **last** `If`

Comment: You must do hiding when you need for ex when ListView is empty and .if it does't go throgh to last if : make sure the control is in form may be button is in SplitContainer or ...

Comment: I grouped my buttons using **Panel1** and **Panel2**

Comment: Panel have a Controls property too.use that property -> Replace this.Controls with  Panel1.Controls and Panel2.Controls .

Comment: you must post your code with your question it can help and ask clearer question